# Why does my code not add a tool bar and a done button to my keyboards?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, custom-keyboard

I followed a tutorial online to add a custom toolbar and a done button to a keyboard. Xcode does not give me any errors, but when I run my app, there is no toolbar or done button an my keyboard. What did I do wrong in my code? Thanks!

**Here is my code-**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let keyboardDoneButtonShow = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(200,200, self.view.frame.size.width,30))

    keyboardDoneButtonShow.barStyle = UIBarStyle .BlackTranslucent
    let button: UIButton = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 20)
    button.setTitle("Done", forState: UIControlState .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("textFieldShouldReturn:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents .TouchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor .clearColor()

    let doneButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    doneButton.customView = button
    let negativeSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpace.width = -10.0
    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let toolbarButton = [flexSpace,doneButton,negativeSpace]
    keyboardDoneButtonShow.setItems(toolbarButton, animated: false)
    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonShow
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
}
```

[Here is my result-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnt00.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not set your TextField's delegate to your View Controller. In `viewDidLoad` add the following:

```
self.textField.delegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I forgot to do that :)